# (Terraform, GCP) Error creating GlobalAddress: googleapi: Error 403: Required > 'compute.globalAddresses.create' permission for > 'projects/myproject-

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to reserve **a global static external IP address** on **GCP** with the **Terraform** code below:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-638932"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "default" {
  name = "global-appserver-ip"
}
```

But I got this error:

> Error creating GlobalAddress: googleapi: Error 403: Required
> 'compute.globalAddresses.create' permission for
> 'projects/myproject-638932/global/addresses/global-appserver-ip',
> forbidden

So now, I'm trying to add a role to solve this error above but there are too many roles to choose:

[image]

What role do I need to choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose the role **"Compute Network Admin"**:

[image]

If you want to choose **a more specific role**, choose the role **"Compute Public IP Admin"**:

[image]

Then, you can reserve **a global static external IP address**:

[image]